# Example code for populating a tensor?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have no idea how to populate a tensor.  The API is not documented very well...

I'd like to have a function kind of like this.

```
std::tuple<std::string, double> CNNLocalizer::runImage()
{
  std::tuple<std::string, double> result;
  result.get<0> = "none";
  result.get<1> = 0.0;

  if (g_got_image_)
  {
    std::string label;

    // create a tensorflow::Tensor with the image information
    tensorflow::TensorShape image_shape;
    image_shape.AddDim(g_img_height_);
    image_shape.AddDim(g_img_width_);

    tensorflow::Tensor input_image(tensorflow::DT_INT8, image_shape);
    // I have no idea how to make this work right now.  Copying data is very confusing..
    for (uint i = 0; i < g_img_height_; i++)
    {
      for (uint j = 0; j < g_img_width_; j++)
      {
        // ??  Populate a matrix or something?
      }
    }
    // Copy the matrix into the tensor?
    // input_image.matrix<float>()() = z;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Any idea how to populate the matrix part of the Tensor?  I found a matrix() function that returns some kind of typedef'd Eigen Tensor object - is that the way to go?

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tensor::FromProto`. Otherwise, it's probably best for you to use `Tensor::flat<int8>`. There are examples for [CSV](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_csv_op.cc#L90) or [PNG](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_png_op.cc#L98).

Comment: Could you provide some more information?  For reference, I have a cv::Mat from a JPG that I would like to put inside a Tensor to run through the graph.  I'm going to dig a bit myself but if you have reference code or any more links I'd be appreciative!

Comment: If you want to be agnostic to data representation, and if it's just a 2d matrix, just use `auto eigen_matrix = input_image.matrix<float>();` as you have it above, then use `eigen_matrix(i, j) = cv_mat[i][j]`. Typically, in an operator, you should allocate the output with `op_kernel_context->allocate_output()`.